# X11/Xorg nail down configuration

Tags: linux, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, xorg

I have two radeon graphics adapters with three displays connected. Two 22″ screens for computing and an AV receiver that is hooked up to the TV.

When the receiver switches input (e.g. from the computer to the blu-ray player or the basic TV), X11 gets notified and re-initializes the displays (which at the current configuration also triggers a segmentation fault in X11 thus terminating the session, but that’s a different story). If I start with the receiver turned off, only two of the screens are connected (and I end up with 2  1920x1200-screens instead of the additional 1920x1080 screen right of it).

I have the system running now exactly as I want it, how can I nail down this configuration so that there’s no plug-and-play dynamic configuration anymore and the output remains, regardless whether the receiver is turned on/off or which input is set?

My OS is OpenSuse Tumbleweed.